# Enviar comandos AT por VB.NET para o Arduino (SIM900)

Tags: vb.net, arduino

Boa tarde, sou novo na parte de programação em Arduino, eu estou com um SIM900 conectado a um arduino UNO, estou fazendo uma aplicação em VB.NET que vai comunicar por SerialPort, que vai mandar mensagem, receber e ver na tela. Porém estou perdido no que tem que colocar para transmitir os dados via serial, no arduino os comandos AT funcionaram legal na tela do terminal, quando vou pro VB.NET o serial.write nao reconhece. Precisa de alguma programação específica para isso no arduino e mandar os comandos pelo VB.NET?

Agradeço pela atenção de todos!